# How to use Win32 API to specify directory to write file to using WriteFile?

Tags: winapi, bitmap, writefile

I've used the following to get a handle to a file:

```
char *filePathAndName = "C:\Projects\pic.bmp";
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(_T(filePathAndName),GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

and I've used the following to write the file:

```
WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)lpbitmap, dwBmpSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
```

However, the file writes to the project directory (i.e. where the Microsoft Visual Studio Solution file exists) rather than to the C:\Projects\ directory.

How can I write the .bmp file to a specified directory?

Comment: You should stop using TCHAR. It makes sense if you need to support NT and Woin 98. Those days are gone. And your casts to LPSTR are bogus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_T()` macro can only be used with literals (same with the `TEXT()` macro).  And you are not escaping the slashes in your literal.

The C runtime uses the `_T()` macro.  The Win32 API uses the `TEXT()` macro.  You should not mix them, even though they effectively do the same thing.  Use the correct macro for the API you are using.

And you don't need to type-cast data to `LPSTR` when calling `WriteFile()`.

Use this instead:

```
LPTSTR filePathAndName = TEXT("C:\\Projects\\pic.bmp");
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(filePathAndName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL); 
...
WriteFile(hFile, &bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, &bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, lpbitmap, dwBmpSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
```

With that said, typically you should be prompting the user for the output filename, either with [`GetSaveFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646928.aspx) or [`IFileSaveDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913.aspx).  Or at least prompt for the destination folder using [`SHBrowseForFolder()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115.aspx) (or [IFileSaveDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913.aspx), which also supports picking a folder) if you want to use your own filename.

Comment: Thanks!  You answered my question and gave other useful info.

Answer (score 3):

This is your problem:

```
char *filePathAndName = "C:\Projects\pic.bmp";
```

Backslash in a string or character literal indicates a special character.  For example, `\t` for tab or `\n` for newline.  The compiler should have complained that `\P` and `\p` aren't valid.

If you have a string that contains real backslashes, you need to double them:

```
char *filePathAndName = "C:\\Projects\\pic.bmp";
```